# If $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable in $\mathbb R$ satisfying $f''(x)=g''(x)$, $f'(1)=2,g'(1)=4,f(2)=3,g(2)=9$, find $f(x)-g(x)$ at $x=4$

Tags: calculus, integration

> If $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable in $\mathbb R$ satisfying $f''(x)=g''(x)$, $f'(1)=2,g'(1)=4,f(2)=3,g(2)=9$, find $f(x)-g(x)$ at $x=4$

My solution: For all $x\in \mathbb R$,
$$\int_0^xf''(x)dx=\int_0^xg''(x)dx$$
Rearranging,
$$f'(x)-g'(x)=f'(0)-g'(0)$$
For $x=1$, $f'(0)-g'(0)=-2$

Again integrating from $0$ to $x$ and rearranging the terms,
$$f(x)-g(x)=f(0)-g(0)+x[f'(0)-g'(0)]$$
For $x=2$, $f(0)-g(0)=-4$

$$f(x)-g(x)=-4-2x$$

> Is this a correct approach? Do I just plug $x=4$ now?

Comment: That cannot be found. It could be anything.

Comment: Answer is given is $2$.

Comment: Just like what you said, all the conditions are on $[0,2]$ only. I can even define $f(x) - g(x) = -4-2x$ when $x\neq 4$ and $f(4) - g(4)=  100$ so the answer is $100$.

Comment: @AdityaDev According to John comment, you should edit your original post. The hypothesis should be change to $f$ and $g$ twice differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This is the actual question. If it was defined on R, then will get the answer by substituting 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f''(x)=g''(x)$$
So $$f'(x)=g'(x)+C$$
Now $$f'(1)=2=4+C$$
So $C=-2$.
Thus $f'(x)+2=g'(x)$.
$$f(x)+2x=g(x)+C_1$$
$$f(2)+2.2=g(2)+C_1$$
$$3+4=9+C_1$$ 
$$C_1=-2$$
So $$f(x)-g(x)=-2-2x$$
So answer will be $-10$.

Comment: It's wrong. $C_1$ is 2

Comment: $f(1)-g(1)-C_1=-2(1)$

Comment: I removed down vote.